# If something happens to the elected president shortly before the inauguration ceremony, who will be the president?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

Suppose there is a newly elected president in USA, however before the official switch (i.e. before the inauguration ceremony takes place) something happens to the elected president and they can't function properly anymore.

Who will be the president until new elections can take place, or until the  newly elected president recovers?

Comment: Related: [What happens when a presidential candidate dies before being inaugurated…?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12138/what-happens-when-a-presidential-candidate-dies-before-being-inaugurated)

Comment: @Panda very related, thanks. Why not duplicate? (I'm not involved enough on this site to tell for sure myself)

Comment: Right, I was slightly more cautious between the distinction of a President-elect dying and becoming incapacitated (your question). Since the 20th amendment [applies in both circumstances](https://www.archives.gov/electoral-college/faq#candidatedies), it’s a duplicate then. (I’m not the downvoter btw.)